# Implementing Line chart in by kendo mvc, need help for horizontal scroll and y axis should be visible

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am implementing Kendo MVC chart in my application, and I am trying to add a horizontal scroll for that. But when I am implementing this, I am not able to see the y-axis of the chart. I also want to see the y-axis in the chart when moving right by horizontal scroll.

I implemented that scroll by CSS. Can I implement the same thing with MVC kendo?

Here is my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
    .Name("chart")     
    .Title("Sales vs. Quotes")
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
    )
    .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea
        .Background("transparent")
    )
    .SeriesDefaults(seriesDefaults =>
        seriesDefaults.Line().Style(ChartLineStyle.Smooth)
    )
    .Series(series =>
    {
        series.Line(ViewBag.lineGraphSales).Name("Sales");
        // series.Line(new double[] { 3.907, 7.943, 7.848, 9.284, 9.263, 9.801, 3.890, 8.238, 9.552, 6.855 }).Name("Sales");
        // series.Line(new double[] { 1.988, 2.733, 3.994, 3.464, 4.001, 3.939, 1.333, -2.245, 4.339, 2.727 }).Name("Quotes");
    })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        // .Categories("Jan-18", "Feb-18", "Mar-18", "APR-18", "MAY-18", "JUN-18", "JUL-18", "AUG-18", "SEP-18", "OCT-18", "NOV-18", "DEC-18")
        .Categories((string[]) ViewBag.lineGraphMonths)
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
    )

    .ValueAxis(axis => axis
        .Numeric()
        .Labels(labels => labels.Format("#,##0,,"))
        .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
        // .AxisCrossingValue(10000)
    )
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Format("${0}")
    )
)
```